# Why selenium not recognizing class in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Selenium is not recognizing the class. I was trying to click an audio button on a website using selenium but it is not recognizing this class

```
class="jumbo--Z12Rgj4 buttonWrapper--x8uow audioBtn--1H6rCK"
```

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=./c")

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Users\Desktop\Scrapping\chromedriver.exe",options=options)
    
driver.get(r"https://www.xx------xx.com")
    
button5 = driver.find_element_by_class_name(r"jumbo--Z12Rgj4")
    
button5.click()
```

But selenium is throwing an exception

> jumbo--Z12Rgj4

Exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".label--Z12LMR3"}
```

Comment: Could you post the error as well please?

Comment: Ya added exception now you can find it

Comment: could give us the full url to reproduce, please.

Comment: Should get logged in to get through the site, it's my college online class website.

Answer (score 1):

If you check again, there would be more than one class 'jumbo--Z12Rgj4', hence selenium is throwing exception.
To make it more dynamic, better use xpath with "contains(@class,'jumbo--Z12Rgj4')", followed by another identifier to make the search unique.

Comment: Can you show me the syntax for Xpath using class

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='label--Z12LMR3']"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Answer (score 1):

The element that you wish to target probably has a uniquely hashed classname every time you load it, because it is not being found at all on the website, so rather than using the classname, try to use its xpath instead.

Comment: Can you show me the syntax for Xpath using class

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='label--Z12LMR3']"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Answer (score 1):

The value of *class* attribute i.e. `jumbo--Z12Rgj4 buttonWrapper--x8uow audioBtn--1H6rCK` is dynamic and will keep on changing everytime you access the application. To click on the element with text as **save** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class^='jumbo']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@class, 'jumbo')]").click()
  ```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class^='jumbo']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@class, 'jumbo')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```